# How to extract a random sample with multiple conditions that vary by group?

Tags: r, random

I have a cross-national data set where each respondent has at least one diary. The number of diaries per respondent and diary completion day varies by country.

For example, in one country each respondent completed only 1 diary (half of the respondents completed only on a weekend, while the other half only on a weekday). In another country, each respondent completed 2 diaries (one weekend- one weekday), and in another one everyone completed 7 diaries (one for each day of the week). There are also surveys where some of the respondents returned 2 diaries, while others 3; and there are those where one everyone returned 4 diaries. The data look like this:

```
country_id<-rep(1:4,c(8,8,14,10))
diarist_id<-c(11:18,rep(21:24,each=2),
              rep(31:32,each=7),
              rep(41:44,c(3,3,2,2)))
diary_id<-c(111:118,211,212,221,222,231,232,241,242,
            311:317,321:327,411,412,413,
            421,422,423,431,432,441,442)
weekend<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
           0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,
           0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)

dat<-data.frame(country_id,diarist_id,diary_id,weekend)
```

I am trying to draw a random sample of “one person-one diary” from each country. But at the country level I need -approximately- 29% of the diaries to be weekend diaries. How can I draw such a conditional random sample by group?

Comment: have you thought about using the `prob` option in `sample`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't know how to integrate conditions in 'sample'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets what you're after. I chose to split the sample for clarity; there's probably a way to get what you want without doing so, but it wasn't coming to me.

I'll use `data.table`:

```
set.seed(100)
library(data.table)
setDT(dat) #turn dat into a data.table (by reference)
country_n<-5 #how many observations you'd like per country

#split the data by weekend status
weekend.dat<-dat[weekend==T]
#we have to take care that there are actually enough
#  weekend observations in each country, so we take the
#  minimum of 29% of country_n (rounded) and the total
#  number of weekend observations in that country
weekend.sample<-
  weekend.dat[weekend.dat[,.I[sample(.N,min(round(.29*country_n),.N))],
                          by=country_id]$V1]

#repeat for the weekday sample, except take 71% this time
weekday.dat<-dat[weekend==F]
weekday.sample<-
  weekday.dat[weekday.dat[,.I[sample(.N,min(round(.71*country_n),.N))],
                          by=country_id]$V1]

#combine; setkey orders the data (as well as other
#  things that may be useful later on)
full.sample<-setkey(rbindlist(list(weekend.sample,weekday.sample)),
                    country_id,diarist_id,diary_id)
```

Here's the sample that produces for my given random seed

```
> full.sample
    country_id diarist_id diary_id weekend
 1:          1         12      112       0
 2:          1         13      113       1
 3:          1         14      114       0
 4:          1         16      116       0
 5:          1         18      118       0
 6:          2         21      212       0
 7:          2         22      221       1
 8:          2         22      222       0
 9:          2         23      232       0
10:          2         24      242       0
11:          3         31      315       0
12:          3         31      316       0
13:          3         31      317       0
14:          3         32      321       1
15:          3         32      324       0
16:          4         41      411       1
17:          4         42      421       0
18:          4         42      423       0
19:          4         43      432       0
20:          4         44      442       0
```

Comment: @Eva note that some `diarist_id` are represented more than once. I wasn't sure from your description whether this is OK. The code above can easily be adjusted (via the `unique` function) to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks! I've just seen this message! Yes, by "one person- one diary" I meant that no diarist_id should be repeated. I will try to adjust the code.